# How to select all the checkboxes in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Hourly" checked="checked">  <input   type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Daily">
    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Weekly" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Monthly">
    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" value="Yearly">
    <br><button id="selectall">Select All</button>
</form>
<script>
    var selectall = function() {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", "true");
    };
    $("#selectall").on("click", selectall);
</script>
```

I have written a JQuery script which will select all the checkboxes when I click on the button "Select All". Now, after selection, I will manually uncheck all the checkboxes and then press "Select All". But this time it fails in selecting all the checkboxes. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

So that's why we have to use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked","true");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kqE4Y/)

Answer (score 0):

USe `prop()` instead of `attr()`

```
var selectall = function() {
     $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked","true");    
};
$("#selectall").on("click", selectall );
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/257/)

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$("#selectall").on("click", function(){
    $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked","true");    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use .prop() instead of .attr(). Try this:

```
var selectall = function() {
     $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked","true");    
};
$("#selectall").on("click", selectall );
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/XBW48/)

prop() vs attr() ref: [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your code should be in dom ready function inside. and use `.prop()` to check all the checkboxes

```
$(function() {

       var selectall = function() {
       $("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked",true);    
       };
       $("#selectall").on("click", selectall );
});
```

Comment: Since OP has declared the script after those form elements, there is no need to wrap the code inside doc ready..